# Generating a CSR from an inf file using .NET

Tags: .net, windows, certificate, pki

I'm using an INF file such as the one below to generate a CSR with "certreq.exe -new -q request.inf request.csr":

```
[Version]
Signature= "$Windows NT$"

[NewRequest]
Subject = "CN=subject"
KeyLength = 2048
Exportable = TRUE
MachineKeySet = TRUE
SMIME = FALSE
PrivateKeyArchive = FALSE
UserProtected = FALSE
UseExistingKeySet = FALSE
ProviderName = "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider"
ProviderType = 12
RequestType = CMC
KeyUsage = 0xa0
KeyAlgorithm = RSA
HashAlgorithm = sha256

[EnhancedKeyUsageExtension]
OID=1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1
```

Is there a way that I can do this via .NET classes, and preferably without having to export the CSR to a file once it is generated?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The closest thing I think you can do is add a COM reference to [`CertEnroll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374863(v=vs.85).aspx) but I don't see a way for that to handle an INF file (there are Win32 APIs, too). The INF file seems to be something that is specific to `certreq`. Do you absolutely have to use the INF file, or just a .NET API that can do what the INF / certreq is doing?

Comment: Hi @vcsjones, a .NET API that can do what the INF file is doing would be okay. Do you have any suggestions/examples? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one way you can do this is with [`CertEnroll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374863(v=vs.85).aspx). CertEnroll cannot process an INF file like your example above, that's unique to certreq (though there is nothing stopping you from parsing the INF yourself).

CertEnroll is a COM library, but still easy enough to use in .NET. First, add a reference to it. Adding a COM reference is a little different. Note though, that CertEnroll is not available on Windows XP or Windows Vista.

First, in your project, right click "References" and select Add Reference. Under the "COM" menu, select "CertEnroll 1.0 Type Library".

The meat of the functionality is the `CX509CertificateRequestCmc` interface. COM interfaces in C# are a bit special, you can "new" them, so this is perfectly valid:

```cs
var req = new CX509CertificateRequestCmc();
```

So, to translate your INF to CertEnroll, I think it would look something similar to this:

```cs
var req = new CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10();
req.Initialize(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextUser);

//Set basic constraints
var basicConstraints = new CX509ExtensionBasicConstraints();
basicConstraints.InitializeEncode(false, 0);
req.X509Extensions.Add((CX509Extension)basicConstraints);

//Set the hash algorithm
var hashAlgorithm = new CObjectId();
hashAlgorithm.InitializeFromAlgorithmName(ObjectIdGroupId.XCN_CRYPT_HASH_ALG_OID_GROUP_ID, 0, 0, "sha256");
req.HashAlgorithm = hashAlgorithm;

//Set the enhanced key usage
var eku = new CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage();
var serverAuth = new CObjectId();
serverAuth.InitializeFromValue("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1");
var oids = new CObjectIds();
oids.Add(serverAuth);
eku.InitializeEncode(oids);
eku.Critical = false;

var privateKey = req.PrivateKey;
//Allow export as the INF does
privateKey.ExportPolicy = X509PrivateKeyExportFlags.XCN_NCRYPT_ALLOW_EXPORT_FLAG;
privateKey.Length = 2048;

//Set the algorithm explicitly
var rsa = new CObjectId();
rsa.InitializeFromAlgorithmName(ObjectIdGroupId.XCN_CRYPT_ANY_GROUP_ID, 0, 0, "RSA");
privateKey.Algorithm = rsa;

privateKey.ProviderName = "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider";
privateKey.ProviderType = X509ProviderType.XCN_PROV_RSA_SCHANNEL; //12
privateKey.KeyUsage = (X509PrivateKeyUsageFlags)0xA0;
privateKey.Existing = false;
privateKey.KeyProtection = X509PrivateKeyProtection.XCN_NCRYPT_UI_NO_PROTECTION_FLAG;
privateKey.MachineContext = true;

var dn = new CX500DistinguishedName();
dn.Encode("CN=subject", X500NameFlags.XCN_CERT_NAME_STR_NONE);
req.Subject = dn;

var cmc = new CX509CertificateRequestCmc();
cmc.InitializeFromInnerRequest(req);
cmc.ArchivePrivateKey = false;
cmc.Encode();
var data = cmc.RawData[EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64REQUESTHEADER];
Console.WriteLine(data);
```

The "data" variable at the end contains the request, all without saving it to disk.

It's quite likely that something is missing from here, but it does generate a certificate request. I would consult the CertEnroll [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374863(v=vs.85).aspx) for any further tweaks that need to be made.